# Find objects with same properties in large List - performance slow

Tags: c#, list

I have a large `List<MyClass>` of objects, around 600000.
`MyClass` has like 10 properties, let's say `property1`, `property2`, etc.. until `property10`.

Out of that list, I want to get a List of `List<MyClass>` with objects having the same value for some of the properties.

That means for example, objects where `property2`, `property4`, `property8` and `property10` are the same.

What is the best way to do that? Currently I do a loop over my `List<MyClass>`, and within that loop I get all similar objects via `List<MyClass>.FindAll()`, dummy code:

```
forach(var item in myClassList)
{
   if(!found.Contains(item))
   {
      var similarObjects = myClassList.FindAll(x => x.property2 == item.property2 && x.property4 == item.property4 && x.property8 == item.property8 && x.property10 == item.property10);

      //adding the objects to the "already found" list
      foreach(var foundItem in similarOjbects)
      {
         found.Add(foundItem);
      }

     if(similarObjects.Count > 1)
     {
        similarObjectsList.Add(similarObjects);
     }
   }
}
```

But it takes ages, the `List.FindAll()` method is very slow.

Is there a more efficient algorithm to do that?

Comment: use `Where()` instead of `FindAll`

Comment: Where does this large list come from? If it comes from a SQL database, it might be more efficient to add a good WHERE clause to your query. Also, it might help if the list is ordered - then you could rewrite the code to exploit that ordering.

Comment: @geo: I think I did that already with similar results

Comment: @S.L. Barth: The list comes deserialized from a file. I decided not to use a DB for my project if possible.

Comment: @geo Not sure why you would want to replace FindAll with Where _in this program_. In fact, it would make things worse, since `similarObjects` would have to be iterated twice. That being said, for this program, GroupBy is what is really needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `group by` to solve this quite efficiently:

```
var grouped =
    from item in myClassList
    group item 
    by new {item.Property2, item.Property4, item.Property8, item.Property10};
```

That will give you a sequence of groups where each group contains all the objects that have the same values for the specified properties.

As an example, to iterate over every item in each group of the resulting sequence of groups you could do something like this:

```
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        // Do something with item
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the type of each property implements `IEquatable<T>` and `GetHashCode()`.

Here's a compilable example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Property1  { get; set; }
        public int Property2  { get; set; }
        public int Property3  { get; set; }
        public int Property4  { get; set; }
        public int Property5  { get; set; }
        public int Property6  { get; set; }
        public int Property7  { get; set; }
        public int Property8  { get; set; }
        public int Property9  { get; set; }
        public int Property10 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data> myClassList = new List<Data>
            {
                new Data {Name = "1A", Property2 = 1, Property4 = 1, Property8 = 1, Property10 = 1},
                new Data {Name = "1B", Property2 = 1, Property4 = 1, Property8 = 1, Property10 = 1},
                new Data {Name = "1C", Property2 = 1, Property4 = 1, Property8 = 1, Property10 = 1},
                new Data {Name = "2A", Property2 = 2, Property4 = 2, Property8 = 2, Property10 = 2},
                new Data {Name = "2B", Property2 = 2, Property4 = 2, Property8 = 2, Property10 = 2},
                new Data {Name = "2C", Property2 = 2, Property4 = 2, Property8 = 2, Property10 = 2},
                new Data {Name = "3A", Property2 = 3, Property4 = 3, Property8 = 3, Property10 = 3},
                new Data {Name = "3B", Property2 = 3, Property4 = 3, Property8 = 3, Property10 = 3},
                new Data {Name = "3C", Property2 = 3, Property4 = 3, Property8 = 3, Property10 = 3},
            };

            var grouped =
                from item in myClassList
                group item 
                by new {item.Property2, item.Property4, item.Property8, item.Property10};

            foreach (var group in grouped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group.Select(item => item.Name)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example above outputs:

```
1A, 1B, 1C
2A, 2B, 2C
3A, 3B, 3C
```

---

**Possible optimisation using PLINQ**

As mentioned by @BertPersyn below, you could perhaps speed this up using PLINQ.

To do that, simply use the following to generate `grouped` (note the addition of `.AsParallel()`):

```
var grouped = 
    from item in myClassList.AsParallel()
    group item 
    by new {item.Property2, item.Property4, item.Property8, item.Property10};
```

To determine if this actually speeds things up, it is imperative that you perform some timings.

Comment: If the CLR allows it, try using Parallel class.

Comment: @BertPersyn Good idea, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out later and let you know how it performed.

Comment: From 10+ hours down to 6 seconds using AsParallel()- absolutely great, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First add a method, `GetUniqueKey`, that returns a unique key (hash) in your class.

Then, use grouping to find items with similar key:

```
List<List<Item>> = items
    .GroupBy(item => item.GetUniqueKey())
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

The GetUniqueKey method should be implemented and optimized based on required properties type. For example, if Property1 and Property2 are integers, you may use the following method:

```
public string GetUniqueKey()
{
    return Prop1.ToString() + "-" + Prop2.ToString();
}
```

OR (more optimized)

```
public object GetUniqueKey()
{
    return new { P1 = Prop1, P2 = Prop2 };
}
```

The `GetUniqueKey` example method itself may not be optimized, you may find another optimized implementation.

Full Example:

```
class Item
{
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}

    public int Prop2 {get; set;}

    public string GetUniqueKey()
    {
        return Prop1.ToString() + "-" + Prop2.ToString();
    }
}

public void DoWork()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 600000; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new Item { Prop1 = rnd.Next(1, 10) });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 600000; i++)
    {
        items[i].Prop2 = rnd.Next(1, 13);
    }

    List<List<Item>> = items
        .GroupBy(item => item.GetUniqueKey())
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Same here, I will try it out later and let you know the results. Currently are two answers, looking forward to test both!

Comment: Also here- from 10+ hours down to 8 seconds - also great, many thanks. However will mark Mathews answer because it is easier to read and also does not require to add an additional method to my class. Nevertheless, many thanks!